# How to overload the Items accessor of a Collection(Of T)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, collections

The code below its written in Vb.Net, but I ask for a Vb.Net or C# example, no matter in the answer.

---

I have a Type like this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class IniKeyCollection : Inherits Collection(Of IniKey)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub Add(ByVal key As IniKey)
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub Add(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Function Contains(ByVal keyName As String) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function IndexOf(ByVal keyName As String) As Integer
    End Function

End Class
```

`IniKey` is a Type with two properties:

```
Public NotInheritable Class IniKey

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As String

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Value = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

End Class
```

What I would like to do is add an overload to the `IniKeyCollection` to access a `IniKey` element by its key name.

I mean, instead of using an index as default:

```
Dim col As New IniKeyCollection
Dim item As IniKey = col(index:=0)
```

Use a string:

```
Dim col As New IniKeyCollection
Dim item As IniKey = col(keyName:="name")
```

...then internally (try to)return the element that matches that key name.

What Is the base member that I need to manipulate for this?, how I could do it?.

Comment: Looks like you are rolling your own dictionary class...

Comment: What happens when an entry like "Name=" appears in more than one section?

Comment: @Plutonix In the real source-code each section is represented by an object named **IniSection**, that object contains the **IniKeyCollection** that reffers only to the keys of that section. Thanks for comment.

Comment: I was just curious.  Not for nothing, but you could save yourself a lot of trouble and code, using serialization rather than INIs in this day and age.

Comment: @Plutonix no problem about your curiosity, I like to answer. I use Xml serialization for specific things, but INI files are better to edit on the fly by the end-ser, in my oppinion, INI files is the best to make "portable" settings of a software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `C#` language syntax item you're looking for is called an indexer.

```
class IniKeyCollection : Collection<IniKey>
{

    private IniKey[] arr = new IniKey[100];

    public IniKey this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return arr.Where(x => x.Name == name).DefaultIfEmpty(null).Single();
        }
        set
        {
            //Not implemented
        }
    }
}
```

You can find out more about them at: [MSDN - C# Programming Guide (Indexers)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> What Is the base member that I need to manipulate for this?

[Collection(Of T).Item Property (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132434(v=vs.110).aspx)

> how I could do it?

```
Default Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal keyName As String) As IniKey
    Get
    End Get
End Property
```